# Нужна ли запятая перед определением, выраженным причастием с зависимыми словами?

Tags: пунктуация

Еще реже встречаются версии стандартов (,) изначально изданные на нескольких официальных языках.

Мне кажется, здесь определяемое существительное само по себе не выражает нужного понятия, и поэтому запятая не ставится. Но может я ошибаюсь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибаетесь. Запятая нужна.

Comment: Т. е. здесь просто причастный оборот?

Comment: "Т. е. здесь просто причастный оборот?"=== Конечно.

Answer (score 0):

Определения, выраженные причастиями и прилагательными с зависимыми словами и стоящие впереди определяемого существительного, обособляются тогда, когда говорящий придаёт им причинное или уступительное значение, например: ***Тронутый преданностью старого кучера,*** Дубровский замолчал и предался своим размышлениям. (Пушкин) (Ср.: Так как Дубровский был тронут преданностью кучера, он замолчал и предался своим размышлениям.)

Comment: Нужна ли запятая перед определением? Перед.